# Breaking out of a PS command after a certain amount of time?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for an example that can break out of the current command if it runs for longer than say, 1 minutes, which would allow me to re-run it.

Here is my script :

```
$ServiceName = 'service'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{

    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service starting'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 3
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
    }

}
```

Comment: you can either use `Get-Date` and compare the datetime info, OR use the `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` stuff to run check for elapsed time, OR use a counter an simply presume your 3 second  sleep is the interval.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks for your answer. Can you send me sample code ?

Comment: put `$Timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()` and  `$Timer.Start()` before your `while` test. then add a 2nd part to that `while` test that checks `$Timer.Elapsed.TotalMinutes`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Use **Start-Job** [Start-Job cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6) to run the process. Then define **Wait-job** 
 [Wait-Job cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-6) with a **-timeout**. The -timeout defines the time for the wait to end and the command prompt will return.

**A point to remember:** -timeout don't display any error messages. Keep that in mind while doing error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Could use some polish, but something like below may work:

```
$ServiceName = 'W32Time'
$arrService  = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
$Interval    = 3
$TimeOut     = 20
$Count       = 0

Start-Service $ServiceName

:SrvCheck While ( $arrService.Status -ne 'Running' )
{
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ( $arrService.Status -eq 'Running' )
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
        Break SrvCheck
    }

    if ( $Count -ge $timeout )
    {
        Write-Host "Timed out wating for service : $ServiceName to start, waited $($Count*$Interval) Seconds..."
        Break SrvCheck
    }

    Write-Host "Waiting for service start, Current Status $($arrService.Status) ... Checks: $Count | Time Elapsed: $($Count*$Interval) ."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $Interval
    ++$Count
}
```

Moved the service start up out of the loop, unless it was your intent to reattempt the start after every failed check.  Even so you may want to put some error handling around it.  I know for example UAC can interfere in a service start request so you may want something there.

So the $TimeOut variable is 20 so each interval being 3 seconds the attempt will time out at 60 seconds.

If you want the check to occur at least once I'd switch this into a Do Until.  With While, if the service starts quickly enough you won't see the message 'Service is now running'

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: after 60 seconds break functon does not correctly working so still working script

Comment: I edited the answer.  The timeout was breaking on time but echo was inappropriate to relay what was happening. I separated it to a separate If block.  I still feel like this is a little messy but seems to be working.  Let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately same still issue

Comment: I tested it against a stopped service with the Start-Service command commented out.  It stopped at exactly 20 checks.

I un-commented the start command and it broke the loop with the correct echo as it should.  Not sure what we're doing different...